# how to find input impedance in AC analysis

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice

I'd say that to find the input impedance, I simply have to add a trace that consists of dividing `vi` by `Ii`, which is the current that goes from the source to the + input of the opamp, but doing so gives me very strange results that are not expected at all. Am I doing it right?
[image]

Comment: Well, tell what you *did* expect. (And add a 220 Ωish resistor from Vb to vo. And try to find an amplifier decades less outdated.)

Comment: What results do you get then, and what's unexpected about them?

Answer (score 2):

LTspice will nicely plot the input impedance over a range of frequencies.

In your circuit, replace source *vi* with a current source and set it's AC value to 1. Run an AC analysis, I usually set it to octave, 200 points per octave, and then whatever frequency range you need. Then probe the the output of the source (the node you have labeled vi) and it will plot the voltage at that point. On the left side of the plot window right click the scale and change the setting from dB to logarithmic and it will display directly in ohms.